# How do I iterate over an enum in Haxe?

Tags: enums, iterator, haxe

I have an enumerator type:

```
enum PlayerProps {
    Attempts;
    Gold;
    Diamonds;
}
```

What should I do to iterate through all enum values? Something like:

```
var props = new Map<PlayerProps, Int>();
for (prop in PlayerProps)
    props[prop] = 0;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Type.allEnums()`](https://api.haxe.org/Type.html?#allEnums):

```
for (prop in Type.allEnums(PlayerProps))
```

Working example on [try.haxe.org](https://try.haxe.org/#a2859).

Comment: Thanks, I've found allEnums a bit later too. But now I have learned that Map can't use enum type as a key...

Comment: Oh, my bad for not testing that, I think you could find a workaround by using the int-value of the enum (it should be accessible somehow) but I guess that is not the best solution for this.
Have you considered creating an object instead of a map? You could define a class that as a field for each property (this may or may not work for your needs)

Comment: I'm trying to find workaround with IntMap and Type.enumIndex method. But this looks quite clumsy.

Comment: @meps Enums in maps should work, they should use: [haxe.ds.EnumValueMap](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/EnumValueMap.html).  If you have issues try type it as `var mProps:EnumValueMap<PlayerProps,Int> = new EnumValueMap()` and see if that makes a difference...